# jQuery - toggle localStorage on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to make a favourite button that saves in local storage and you can toggle on and off.

But I am having trouble toggling local storage value on click.

This is what I have:

```
$(fav).click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem('favourited', 'yes');
      $(this).toggleClass('favourite');
});
```

I've tried using `removeItem` if the item is set on load but, this will just remove it once and not allow toggle.

Comment: Just FYI don't use 'yes' and 'no' strings for toggleable state properties, use boolean `true` and `false`

Comment: what if you make it a number like `1` or  `-1` and just multiply it by `-1` to toggle it. Other way would be to get it then change it, like
 `localStorage.setItem('favourited', (localStorage.getItem("favourited") == "yes" ? "no": "yes"));`

Or as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned you can make it a boolean

Comment: @SASSY_ROG or just a boolean like I said. Then it becomes `!value` to toggle it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh yes, just read your first response, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditions for the class to define wheter it's favourited or not.

```
$(fav).on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('favourite');
    // Define wheter its a favourite item based on the class
    let val = $(this).hasClass('favourite') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    // Set the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('favourited', val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hasClass()` method to check the class exist or not then  toggle the localStorage according to that:

```
$(fav).click(function() {
  // if there is a class we set "No" to local storage
  // because the code for toggle will remove that class from the HTML
  var value = $(this).hasClass('favourite') ? 'No' : 'yes';
  localStorage.setItem('favourited', value);
  $(this).toggleClass('favourite');
});
```

**Illustration**

```js
var fav = $('.btn');
$(fav).click(function() {
  // if there is a class we set "No" to local storage because the code for toggle will remove that class from the HTML
  var value = $(this).hasClass('favourite') ? 'No' : 'yes';
  console.log(value);
  $(this).toggleClass('favourite');
});
```

```css
.favourite {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be smth like this

```
$(fav).click(function(){

      // You should rely on the data from your local storage since user can reload your application and you cannot rely on your memory or html classes
      const fav = localStorage.getItem('favourited');

      if (fav) {
        localStorage.removeItem('favourited');
        $(this).removeClass('favourite');
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('favourited', 'yes');
        $(this).addClass('favourite');
     }
});
```